# How to repackage a group of jbi component installers in a single installer for servicemix

Tags: java, maven, esb, apache-servicemix, jbi

I have a set of jbi component installers in the hotdeploy folder of my servicemix/esb instance. In particular servicemix-camel, servicemix-mail and servicemix-shared.

I would like to create a single installer using maven and the jbi plugin(call it servicemix-all) that includes the 3 above components as dependencies(plus a few). Then I would only place the servicemix-all installer in my hotdeploy folder which would hopefully install the sub-components.

Is this possible? Essentially, is there a jbi component that can install other components? Or, is there a way to extend an existing component without the source?

servicemix-version: 2011.02.0-fuse-00-89 (3.X)

jbi-plugin-version: 4.5